# Contagem regressiva em JS - Como inserir um "zero" à frente dos numeros menores do que 9?

Tags: javascript, contador

encontrei um script muito simples e funcional para fazer contagem regressiva, mas ele tem um problema; quando o contador chega a 9, deixa de ter dois caracteres, algo que acaba estragando bastante o alinhamento que tive que fazer para estruturar o CSS. Alguém sabe como resolver, inserindo um "0' na frente dos números menores do que 9?

```
<div class="contador_ajuste_largura">
   <div class="contador" >
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function atualizaContador(YY,MM,DD,HH,MI,saida) {
            var SS = 00;
            var hoje = new Date();
            var futuro = new Date(YY,MM-1,DD,HH,MI,SS);

            var ss = parseInt((futuro - hoje) / 1000);
            var mm = parseInt(ss / 60);
            var hh = parseInt(mm / 60);
            var dd = parseInt(hh / 24);

            ss = ss - (mm * 60);
            mm = mm - (hh * 60);
            hh = hh - (dd * 24);

            var faltam = '';
            faltam += (dd && dd > 1) ? dd+'&nbsp:&nbsp;' : (dd==1 ? '1 dia, ' : '');
            faltam += (toString(hh).length) ? hh+'&nbsp:&nbsp;' : '';
            faltam += (toString(mm).length) ? mm+'&nbsp:&nbsp;' : '';
                faltam += (toString(mm).length) ? ss+'&nbsp' : '';

            if (dd+hh+mm+ss > 0) {
                document.getElementById(saida).innerHTML = faltam;
                setTimeout(function(){atualizaContador(YY,MM,DD,HH,MI,saida)},1000);
            } else {
                document.getElementById(saida).innerHTML = '';
                setTimeout(function(){atualizaContador(YY,MM,DD,HH,MI,saida)},1000);
            }
         }

         window.onload=function(){
            atualizaContador('2017','11','23','23','59','elemento');
         }
      </script>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você verificar se o numero é igual ou menor que `9`, e inserir o `0` na frente.

```js
let numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

for(let i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++){
  if(numeros[i] <= 9){
    numeros[i] = '0' + numeros[i]
  }
  console.log(numeros[i])
}
```

Caso queira ver isso funcionando no seu exemplo

```js
function atualizaContador(YY,MM,DD,HH,MI,saida) {
  var SS = 00;
  var hoje = new Date();
  var futuro = new Date(YY,MM-1,DD,HH,MI,SS);

  var ss = parseInt((futuro - hoje) / 1000);
  var mm = parseInt(ss / 60);
  var hh = parseInt(mm / 60);
  var dd = parseInt(hh / 24);

  ss = ss - (mm * 60);
  mm = mm - (hh * 60);
  hh = hh - (dd * 24);
  
  ss = ss <= 9 ? '0' + ss : ss
  mm = mm <= 9 ? '0' + mm : mm
  hh = hh <= 9 ? '0' + hh : hh

  var faltam = '';
  faltam += (dd && dd > 1) ? dd+'&nbsp:&nbsp;' : (dd==1 ? '1 dia, ' : '');
  faltam += (toString(hh).length) ? hh+'&nbsp:&nbsp;' : '';
  faltam += (toString(mm).length) ? mm+'&nbsp:&nbsp;' : '';
  faltam += (toString(mm).length) ? ss+'&nbsp' : '';

  if (dd+hh+mm+ss > 0) {
    document.getElementById(saida).innerHTML = faltam;
    setTimeout(function(){atualizaContador(YY,MM,DD,HH,MI,saida)},1000);
  } else {
    document.getElementById(saida).innerHTML = '';
    setTimeout(function(){atualizaContador(YY,MM,DD,HH,MI,saida)},1000);
  }
}

window.onload=function(){
  atualizaContador('2017','11','23','23','59','contador');
}
```

```html
<div id="contador"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Faz um `if` verificando se o numero é menor que 9

```
if (numero <= 9){
  var numero = '0' + numero
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes fazer isso de maneira mais económica...

Sugestão:

```js
function atualizaContador(futuro, mostrador, callback) {
  var el = document.getElementById(mostrador);

  var contador = setInterval(function() {
    var agora = new Date();
    var diff = futuro - agora;
    if (diff <= 0) {
      callback();
      return clearInterval(contador);
    }
    var ss = diff / 1000;
    var mm = ss / 60;
    var hh = mm / 60;
    var dd = hh / 24;
    var falta = [dd, hh, mm, ss % 60].map(nr => ('0' + Math.floor(nr)).slice(-2));
    el.innerHTML = falta.join(':');

  }, 1000);

}

window.onload = function() {
  var final = new Date(2017, 11, 23, 23, 59);
  atualizaContador(final, 'mostrador', function() {
    alert('É Natal!');
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="mostrador"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução bem simples é utilizar a função [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) da `String`, que lhe garante o tamanho e preenchimento com zeros.

Veja o exemplo:

```js
let horas = 2;
let minutos = 8;
let segundos = 9;

let relogio = horas.toString().padStart(2,"0") + ":" + 
              minutos.toString().padStart(2,"0") + ":" + 
              segundos.toString().padStart(2,"0");
              
console.log(relogio);
```

A função foi chamada com `2` no primeiro parâmetro que é a quantidade de careteres a mostrar, e com `"0"` no segundo parâmetro, que é o caratere a fazer o preenchimento.

No exemplo que tem seria aplicado na variável `faltam` não necessitando de fazer as verificações `ss = ss <= 9 ? '0' + ss : ss` que tem.

Veja como ficaria aplicado no seu código:

```js
function atualizaContador(YY,MM,DD,HH,MI,saida) {
  var SS = 00;
  var hoje = new Date();
  var futuro = new Date(YY,MM-1,DD,HH,MI,SS);

  var ss = parseInt((futuro - hoje) / 1000);
  var mm = parseInt(ss / 60);
  var hh = parseInt(mm / 60);
  var dd = parseInt(hh / 24);

  ss = ss - (mm * 60);
  mm = mm - (hh * 60);
  hh = hh - (dd * 24);

  let faltam = (dd && dd > 1) ? dd+'&nbsp:&nbsp;' : (dd==1 ? '1 dia, ' : '') +
            hh.toString().padStart(2,"0") + ":" +
            mm.toString().padStart(2,"0") + ":" + 
            ss.toString().padStart(2,"0");

  if (dd+hh+mm+ss > 0) {
    document.getElementById(saida).innerHTML = faltam;
    setTimeout(function(){atualizaContador(YY,MM,DD,HH,MI,saida)},1000);
  } else {
    document.getElementById(saida).innerHTML = '';
    setTimeout(function(){atualizaContador(YY,MM,DD,HH,MI,saida)},1000);
  }
}

window.onload=function(){
  atualizaContador('2017','11','23','23','59','contador');
}
```

```html
<div id="contador"></div>
```